# Does using the `iter' function consume a generator?

Tags: python

For example, if I do something like the following:

```py
def test():
    yield from range(100)
testing = test()
iter(testing)
```

If the `iter` function returns an iterator, but the result of the function call isn't assigned to a variable, why does running `print(list(testing))` or similar return all the values? I thought converting a generator would consume the items inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

No, the *iter()* function does not consume an iterator; instead, it returns the iterator unchanged.

### Annotated code

Here's what all the objects are called and what they are doing:

```
def test():                  # generator creation function
    yield from range(100)

testing = test()             # generator/iterator object

t2 = iter(testing)           # t2 and testing are identical

list(testing)                # runs the iterator to exhaustion

list(testing)                # this time you get an empty list
```

### Explained

A generator object is a kind of iterator.  They only run forward and run once.  Calling `next(it)` retrieves a value and advances the iterator.  Calling `iter(it)` returns the same iterator unchanged.   To make a fresh new iterator, just call the generator creation function again: `testing2 = test()`.

Comment: Got it, and accepted as the answer; thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

An *iterable* is something with a `__iter__` method. An *iterator* is something with a `__next__` method. The job of the `iter` function is to call the `__iter__` method to get an *iterable*. These could all be the same, or different objects, depending on how they are implemented. Notably, the iterator does not consume the iterable. Although an *iterable* may return a different *iterator* object (for instance a `list` returns a `list_iterator` object), almost all *iterators* just return themselves. that way you don't have to check whether you already have an *iterator* when doing an iteration.

Comment: *"almost all iterators just return themselves"* - Can you name one that doesn't? They're required to do that.

Comment: Ah; got it. "The job of the `iter` function is to call the `__iter__` method to get an _iterable_." That cleared things up. Thanks!

Comment: @KellyBundy - from the docs: _CPython implementation detail: CPython does not consistently apply the requirement that an iterator define __iter__()._ As importantly, non-conforming iterators may implement an `__iter__` that creates a new object. One should not count on returned iterators always meeting the "is" test. The idea that I somehow have to review or justify all iterators ever written is just silly. If someone is implementing an foreign function interface for instance, it may be easier to create a new iter every time.

Comment: One should not count on something that's required? Then there's probably *a lot* we should not count on, including stuff you count on as well. And I don't see what's easier than `return self`.

Comment: @KellyBundy - Right. I gave you a direct quote from the documentation that not all stdlib iterators implement `__iter__` so, if you tried `iter(stdlib_iterator)` it would fail. Add in the world of modules outside of the stdlib, and yeah, you gotta be careful. So, "almost all".

Comment: Hmm, I interpreted that differently. As in, CPython doesn't "check"/"enforce" the requirement. Not as saying that it has violating iterators itself.

Comment: And judging by the description of the [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/be36e0634060c7d5dee8e8876fb888bbb53d992a) that introduced that note, I believe my interpretation is the correct one. I'll check out its issue's discussion tomorrow.